# whatsapp not connecting to network until opened

Tags: applications, wi-fi, whatsapp-messenger, connection-issues, dns

The problem is only with whatsapp app, only in my android device and only when connected to my WiFi.
Background data is turned on.
Battery optimization is off.
Account sync is enabled.
Proxy is none.
DNS is 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4.
Could anyone please help. Thankyou

Comment: Whatsapp uses Google Push notifications, therefore battery optimization has to be disabled not only for Whatsapp itself but also for GooglePlayServices.

Comment: battery optimization is totally disabled. Still the problem exist.  Only sometimes i'm facing the problem. Tried many ways. Its not when the battery is low and not when whatsApp is removed from recent tasks. I couldn't figure out when and what's causing it .